# Get windows logs from server, to my website

Tags: https, event-log, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to get the eventlog from my windows 2012 r2 server, and display this, is any errors had occured.

I have found out on how to archive and filter the eventlog from the command line.

I guess the way to go now, is somehow to run actions on the command line of my server, but how do i do that so i can get the data to my website, whilst being secure?

Comment: You want to publish your server's event log to your website?

Comment: Are you running a .NET application?

Comment: Yes it will be .net. No i dont want to publish them, i want to inform tech employess that an application error has occured.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an application wide error logger such as [ELMA](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

You can install ELMAH in an ASP.NET application via the NuGet package and it will automatically log all errors and you can examine those errors through a pre-configured route or by inspecting the error logs remotely.

Make sure you secure the the handler for displaying error logs properly. See this SO post for information on how to do it: [How to secure Elmah.axd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416318/how-to-secure-elmah-axd)